# ESL: Multiplying Matrix $X$ by $X^T = 2X^T$?

Tags: matrices, statistics, least-squares, linear-regression

In Elements of Statistical Learning, we differentiate $RSS(β) = (y - X\beta)^T (y - X\beta)$ (equation 2.4) w.r.t to $\beta$ to get $X^T(y - X\beta)$ (equation 2.5).

According to some([link](https://getd.libs.uga.edu/pdfs/ma_james_c_201412_ms.pdf)), this is because $$(y - X\beta)^T(y - X\beta) = y^T y -2\beta^T X^T y+\beta^T X^T X \beta$$
I understand how differentiating from here would lead to equation 2.5. What I don't understand is where the $-2\beta^T X^T y$ term comes from. Don't we get $-X^T\beta^T y$ and $-X\beta y$ multiplying out $(y - X\beta β)^T(y - X\beta)$? Combining those terms shouldn't result in $-2β^T X^T y$ given that $X$ isn't guaranteed to be symmetric right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noting that in this context, $y$ is a $N \times 1$ column vector, $\beta$ is a $(p + 1) \times 1$ column vector, and $X$ is an $N \times (p+1)$ matrix, so $\beta^T X^T y$ is a scalar value, and as such is guaranteed to be symmetric regardless of $X$.

Comment: Thank you the in depth explanation!

Answer (score 2):

We should get $\beta^TX^Ty$ and $y^TX\beta$. Note that this is a scalar.

Hence $\beta^TX^Ty=y^TX\beta$.

Comment: This assumes $\beta$ is a vector quantity rather than a matrix, but this does seem to match the underlying context.

Comment: i check ESL, $\beta$ is a vector if I understand correctly.

Comment: Thank you the explanation!